# Job-buffer for IDocument

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I create a plugin for Eclipse. How can I add an event to job-buffer for IDocument?

Situation:
I need to disable immediate changes in a text editor (currently inscribed character). Instead, I want to assign these events to buffer Job to be carried out after the Job, which is located in front of them.

Comment: I suppose that IDocument has queue (job-buffer-around I badly expressed) for the event.

Comment: I would like to add the queue of actions. So if a change is made in the editor, it will be register only after actions, which are made ​​before the change event and actions stand before the change. The action means any artificial correction of the text.